# bash on Linux, delete files with certain file extension

Tags: linux, bash, file, delete-file

I want to delete all files with a specific extension - "*.fal*", in a folder and its subfolders, except the one named "*Original.fal". The problem is that I want to delete other files that have the same extension:

- *Original.fal.ds
- *Original.fal.ds.erg
- *Original.fal.ds.erg.neu

There are other "*.fal*"s that I want to delete as well, that don't have "Original" in them.
Names vary all the time, so I can't delete specific names. The *Original.fal doesn't vary.

I can only get up to here:

```
$find /disk_2/people/z183464/DOE-Wellen -name "*.fal" \! -name "*Original.fal" -type f -exec echo rm {} \;
```

It would be great if the command can delete only in the folder (and it's subfolders) where it has been called (executed)

When I run the code it gives me an error:

1. /disk_2/people/z183464/DOE-Wellen: is a directory

Comment: http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/Unix/FindCmd.htm

Comment: Just rename the file you don't want to delete, then do a simple rm, then rename the file back again.

Comment: Your `find` solution should work fine.  The error message seems just because you typed your one-liner on two lines.  That `-type f`-stuff should be on the same line as the stuff above, then it should function.  Hint:  use `-exec echo rm {} \;` to see what it *would* do before actually executing it without the `echo`.

Comment: Yep, I got it back to the first line, but the first error still stays. How can I do the same, without specifying the folder, but do it instead in the folder that it's being executed (called)

Comment: Aside from the pointers others have given, I want to point out : "*.fal" __is not what you want__. that gets files ending in .fal. In other words, only `*Original.fal` would match. You probably want "*.fal.*" which will actually get all files that contain '.fal.' -- IOW, it will select all of the items you listed but not "*Original.fal".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want `find` to dive too deep, you can restrict it with `-maxdepth`.

Comment: @Vihar: Well, the question changed :-) You have to backslash the exclamation mark, it is a special character in bash (related to history expansion).

Comment: Yes it did change :) I've tried with \ before and after the exclamation mark - still the same...

Comment: @Vihar: Putting a backslash after the exclamation mark quotes the space. Before shoudl be enough.

Comment: I was saying i tried both. I had a mistake, putting -type on the next line, so the second error is gone now. But the first one stays even with the backslash before the exclamation mark.

Comment: @Vihar: Move the `-type` condition before the negation.

Comment: Don't really get what you advise me to do...What is the negation?

Comment: Still the same..... I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong with the folder path. How can I tell it to look for those files in the folder I run the command in?

Comment: `find /disk_2/people/z183464/DOE-Wellen -name "*.fal.*" -type f \! -name "*Original.fal.*" -exec echo rm {} \;`

Comment: @Vihar: You are trying to execute a directory. Did you include the dollar sign in front of `find` to the command line?

Comment: Yes. It still just gives me: ../: is a directory

Comment: @Vihar: Remove the dollar sign. It is a part of the prompt, not of the command. Note I did not use it.

Comment: Ok. Some progress :) now it says: 

find:paths must precede expression
Usage: find [-H][-L][-P][path...][expression]

Comment: @Vihar: Works for me. Please copy and paste the exact line I gave you.

Comment: IM AN IDIOT. I have no idea what I did wrong, but now it works as a charm. Can't tell you how much you helped me!!!! THANKS!

Comment: @choroba: +1 for the user support (and your calm during it, in the comments) ^^. And +1 to Vihar for  persistence and ability to change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple for loop for that. This command shows all the files you might want to delete. Change echo with rm to delete them.

```
cd /disk_2/people/z183464/DOE-Wellen && for I in `find . -name "*.fal" ! -name "*Original.fal"`; do echo $I; done
```

With "find ... | grep ..." you can use regex too, if you need more flexibility.

Comment: When I run the code it gives me:

/disk_2/people/z183464/DOE-Wellen: is a directory